# How to change a variable using onclick

Tags: javascript, function, variables, onclick

I'm trying to change a variable from 0 to 4 using an onclick function in html. Below is roughly what I have.
The javascript / HTML :

```js
function openTab(evt, page) 
{
    var i, pages, links;
    //hide all pages
    pages = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
    for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        pages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    //remove active tab
    links = document.getElementsByClassName("link");
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].className = links[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
    //set active page and tab
    document.getElementById(page).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

var y=0; 
var x=10; 
var hp=x-y 
var changeVariable = function(){ 
    alert("before : "+y) 
    y = 4; 
    alert("after : "+y);
//adding result to element
document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = hp;
}
//binding click onto element 
document.getElementByid("clickMe").addEventListener("click", changeVariable );
```

```html
  <button Id="clickMe">
 click me ! 
</button>
<div  id="myResult">
</div>
```

The top part of the javascript is for my tabs on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using inline event handlers since using them is a bad practice. You could achieve what you want be doing like this

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var y=0;
  var x=10;
  var h=x-y;

document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = h;

var changeVariable = function(){
 y = 4;
 h = x - y;
 //Adding the result to an element
 document.getElementById("myResult").innerHTML = h;
}

//Binding "click" on an element

  document.getElementById("clickMe").addEventListener("click", changeVariable);
});
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">
  click me !
</button>
<div id="myResult">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Copied and pasted so I dont make any mistakes. For some reason it isnt showing. On my original code I had a document.write(h) at the end so it would appear at the top of my html page. Would I have to do something similar?

Comment: So you're trying to display it on your HTML ? You should use `Element.innerHTML` to replace the HTML of your element and not just append your result to the document. Like you can see in my edit.

Comment: It has come up with an error "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

Comment: You have no element with an `id="clickMe"` then.

Comment: I do. Its in the html and I triple checked the spelling.its in the solo learn app if that's any help.

Comment: Can you edit and post your complete code ? (HTML + JS) As you ca see, my code snippet runs properly so you must be messing something.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Javascript (which has nothing to do with java scripts) is case sensitive, therefore in `getElementByid` the `i` should be capital `I` ! Replace it by : `getElementById` and it will work fine.

Comment: Still getting the same issue.

Comment: I just copied / paste your code, it works fine : https://jsfiddle.net/wa67ne6p/ . Where de you call your script ?

Comment: The DOM is not loaded when `adventListener` is bound, you'll have to tell your page to wait until document is ready. I edited my code.

Comment: Excellent. I can see it now. Tho I dont want the alert boxes, I just wanna see the var h before and after y has been changed. Sorry to be a pain. And thank you very much for helping.

Comment: I edited my code to do just that. Don't worry, we've all been there ;)

Comment: Sorted. Thankyou my friend!!! If I new how, I would bake you a cake to say thankyou :D

Comment: Out of curiosity.  How would you go about adding other variables into the equation, e.g. h= x - y - z - w. X being 10 and the others having their own onclick function?

Comment: You could do it by various way, since you're new to all this, you can try to bind  `input`s to your variable and trigger the calculation on input change.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="action" onclick="y=4"> click </a>
```

This one might work.

Answer (score 0):

Onclick Just call a function which updates value of y and pass new value as argument

Ex:

```
<html>
<body>
 <a href="action" onclick="updateValue(4);"> click </a>
</body>
<script>
 var y=0;
 var x=10;
 var h=x-y
 function updateValue(newValue){
    y = newValue;
 }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Very much enjoy the simplicity of yours, tho it doesnt appear on my html. I have a document.write(h) element at the end of the script tag. Could that be causing it?